# HTTP call using DELETE fails on iOS, succeeds on Android

Tags: ios, cordova, vue-resource

I'm calling an API from a Cordova (Monaca) app using Vue.js. The code is platform-agnostic and works well with Android and the browser preview. The relevant part just calls `this.$http.delete(url, config)` and logs the response. `this.$http` comes from https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource.

On iOS, I'm getting this when I log the response:

```
{
  "url": "https://domain.whatever?KEY=12345&receipt_id=12345",
  "ok": false,
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  "body": "",
  "bodyText": ""
}
```

The same call, on Android, gets this result:

```
{
  "url": "https://domain.whatever?KEY=12345&receipt_id=12345",
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "connection": [
        "Keep-Alive"
      ],
      "content-encoding": [
        "gzip"
      ],
      "content-length": [
        "17"
      ],
      "content-type": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "date": [
        "Mon, 12 Apr 2021 12:51:56 GMT"
      ],
      "keep-alive": [
        "timeout=5, max=100"
      ],
      "server": [
        "Apache"
      ],
      "vary": [
        "Accept-Encoding"
      ]
    }
  },
  "body": {
    "status": "OK"
  },
  "bodyText": "{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
}
```

(Logs are slightly edited to remove private data and indented for readability.)

What can explain the failure with iOS? Is there some kind of default filter applied by iOS to block HTTP DELETE requests? POST and GET requests seem to behave consistently across mobile platforms.

Comment: is it only DELETE that fails ? Do POST work ?

Comment: Yes @Eric. Only DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

By default iOS blocks unsecure HTTP requests:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections

Check the **Configure Exceptions Only When Needed; Prefer Server Fixes** section to see how you add override this behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that's insightful! All connections are HTTPS though, is there any reason why a DELETE request might end up being blocked and a GET request would regularly flow through?

Comment: sorry, I missed that your requests are HTTPS. 
Not sure if this is your case, but there was a bug affecting WKWebView on iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653662

Setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*' is not enough, you should set it to the same value as the request 'Origin' header.

Comment: It might be! Still not easy to find out if this is the culprit because I'm buried under a huge stack of frameworks, libraries etc. and it's not easy to find out the actual configuration enforced.